# Create functions from array values

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to see if there's a way to create functions from array values.

I have an array of database table names:

```
Array
(
    [0] => table1
    [1] => table2
    [2] => table3
    [3] => table4
    [4] => table5
)
```

etc... I want to be able to produce a function with each of the table names:

```
public function table1()
{
    // function code here...
}

public function table2()
{
    // function code here...
}
```

The code in each function will be the same for now. Just trying to get the function created every time a new table is added to the database.

Thanks!

Each function will look something like this when done:

```
public function tablename()
{
    $obj = new obj();
    $obj->set_table('tablename');

    $this->_output_view($obj->render());
}
```

Comment: Is this going to be inside of a class?

Comment: Also, what do you want each of these to do?  Once you dynamically create each function, what do you want its body to be?  Making them all have the same body is possible... making them all be different is harder (if even possible).

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps `call_user_func` is the right for you.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve.  If this is in a class, maybe you can use `function __call()` instead of actually trying to create functions.

Comment: Yes this will be inside a class. Basically I'm setting up controller views. Each function is represented by http://www.site/class/function_name. Each function is creating a new class object, setting the table (function name) then rendering the page.

Comment: It seems you are skipping the whole concept of a model for some reason? Perhaps look into a good ORM like Propel or Doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is inside of a class, then you can use the [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) "magic method" in PHP.  Basically, in a class, this is called whenever you do `$obj->func()`, regardless of whether the function exists or not.

So, you can just do the action needed without creating functions.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Tables{
    private $tables;

    function __construct(){
        // Your array of tables
        $this->tables = array(
            'table1',
            'table2',
            'table3'
        );
    }

    // This is automatically called when doing $yourObj->table1(), for example
    function __call($name, $params=array()){
        // Check if the method called is a table name
        if(in_array($name, $this->tables)){
            // If so, then do whatever with the table name
            $obj = new obj();
            $obj->set_table($name);

            $this->_output_view($obj->render());
        }
        // Let's make sure to pass on the call to other methods in this class
        elseif(method_exists($this, $name)){
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $params);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket. That's pretty much what I was looking for. The framework I'm using has some weird issue with the __call method but they have their own _remap() which basically does the same thing. Thanks again!